# REST GET request on Python sending named argument

Tags: python, rest, urllib2

I am playing from Linux using curl inside bash but now I need to move my script to python in order to be more effective. 
What is the best way to do something like the following line on python?

```
curl baseuri:port/resource -u user:pswd
```

I played already with urllib2 but I dont get a clue on how to send the "-u user:pswd"

Comment: See http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm) to handle the authentication, and add in a [`HTTPBasicAuthHandler` handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler) to respond to the authentication challenge:

```
import urllib2

url = 'baseuri:port/resource'
username = 'user'
password = 'pswd'

pwmgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pwmgr.add_password(None, url, username, password)    
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
response = opener.open(theurl)
```

Yes, this is a handful.

If you can install a 3rd party library, then add use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/); it'll be so much easier:

```
import requests

url = 'baseuri:port/resource'
username = 'user'
password = 'pswd'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we use pycurl instead which also works pretty well. Here an example to get a json from the request:

```
    import pycurl
    import json
    from io import BytesIO

    data = BytesIO()
    pyCurl = pycurl.Curl()
    pyCurl.setopt(pyCurlClass.URL,string_http)
    pyCurl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'user:password')
    pycurl.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, data.write)
    pyCurl.perform()

    dictionary = json.loads(data.getvalue())
```

Comment: `pycurl` is very low level; your sample here does not include the code required to receive the response, for example, which requires passing in a file object.  The Python integration is rather... unpythonic.

Comment: totally, it's a very low level. I use the same approach when developing libraries in C.

Comment: Except for very specific cornercases, however, `pycurl` is not a tool I can recommend. Certainly not for someone just learning Python and trying to execute a simple GET request with authentication.

Comment: thank you. I tried but had issues at installing, there are some threads where it is shown how it fails installing with pip.